# RESTful web service with apache cxf

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, cxf

I've already developed a SOAP web service in Java with apache cxf and now I've to develop the same services in RESTful.

I have some troubles to deploy the web service on my tomcat. In fact, I don't know how should I configure my `web.xml` or any other XML file.

There are many examples online but everything I've tried so far doesn't work.

To build the project, I use an Ant build tool.

Anyone knows some good tips?

Comment: Could you paste your service class? And what have you tried already? CXF is a solid framework and has a solid documentation. They have many example in their documentation to demonstrate this kind of behaviour. So if you need help, you must show what have you tried and what error did you get.

Answer (score 1):

Here my service class used to test tutorials

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/book")
public class BookService {

@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({"application/xml","application/json"})
public Book getBookForId(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    Book book = null
    book = DB.getBookForId();
    if(book == null){
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    }else{
        return Response.ok(book).build();
    }
}
```

}

And my web.xml looks like this most of the time :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
    <display-name>REST</display-name>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Apache CXF's example and other examples are "easy" to understand but the fast is that what i've done until now won't work.

My web service is deployed on my tomcat but everytime there is error like this :

```
 Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path [/WebServices] threw exception [L''exécution de la servlet a lancé une exception] with root cause
java.lang.AbstractMethodError:     javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:669)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

I know that this kind of error are stupid btu i don't get it Zzz.

I have to use jdk 1.6.0.45 so i can't try example which use jdk 1.7 and higher version. The fact is most of example tell to use Jersey 2.18...